# FluentAssertions alternative of TrueForAll

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

I'm trying to find an alternative of `.TrueForAll` using FluentAssertions. Note that in the Shoudly example Products is `List<Product>` whereas in the new code it is `IEnumerable<Product>`.

It says `A constant value is expected` for minPrice and maxPrice:

```cs
actual.Products.All(x => x.Price is >= minPrice and <= maxPrice).Should().BeTrue(); // A constant value is expected

// or
actual.Products.Should().OnlyContain(x => x.Price is >= minPrice and <= maxPrice); // A constant value is expected
```

### Shoudly (old code)

```cs
[Theory]
[InlineData(10)]
[InlineData(12)]
[InlineData(5)]

public async Task Handle_ReturnsFilteredProductByMaxPrice(double maxPrice)
{
    var parameters = new ProductParams() { MaxPrice = maxPrice };

    var result = await _handler.Handle(new GetProductsQuery(parameters), CancellationToken.None);

    result.Value.Products.TrueForAll(x => x.Price <= maxPrice);
}
```

### FluentAssertions (new code)

```cs
[Theory]
[InlineData(10, 14)]
[InlineData(22, 24)]
public async Task Handle_ShouldReturnFilteredSubsetOfProducts_WhenGivenMinPriceAndMaxPrice(double minPrice, double maxPrice)
{
    // Arrange
    var query = new GetProductsQuery(MinPrice: minPrice, MaxPrice: maxPrice);

    // Act
    var actual = await _queryHandler.Handle(query, default);

    // Assert
    actual.Products.All(x => x.Price is >= minPrice and <= maxPrice).Should().BeTrue();
}
```

```cs
public record Product(
    [property: JsonPropertyName("title")] string Title,
    [property: JsonPropertyName("price")] double Price,
    [property: JsonPropertyName("sizes")] List<string> Sizes,
    [property: JsonPropertyName("description")] string Description);
```

Comment: It's a typo, that's invalid syntax. It should be `x.Price >= minPrice` and not `x.Price is >= minPrice`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://fluentassertions.com/collections/

```
actual.Products.Should().OnlyContain(x => x.Price >= minPrice && x.Price <= maxPrice)
```

The error you're getting comes from incorrect use of pattern matching - the values after `is` need to be constant, not a variable.

Comment: Yep. Orion is right.

Comment: So it's a typo.